# Check for next day

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am trying to create a ticket counter, basically when the user clicks on the button ie. create ticket, the counter will increment by 1 until the next day the ticket counter will reset back to 0 again.

I have stored the counter in a database, so the database knows the last counter for a particular user. But how can I reset the counter back to 0, as soon as the user clicks the button the next day. I have a function called checkformidnight as follows but don't think this is the right way.

```
Private Function CreatTicketNumber(ByVal officerId As Integer) As String

    Dim counter As Integer = officer.Officer_Ticket_Counter '' from database
    If IsMidnight(Now) Then
        counter = 0
    Else
        counter = counter + 1
    End If


    Dim TicketNumber As String = counter.ToString("00")

    Return TicketNumber
End Function


Public Function IsMidnight(ByVal value As Date) As Boolean
    Return value.TimeOfDay.Ticks = 0
End Function
```

Comment: You probably don't want the C# tag.  I left it so you can see how that goes

Comment: You may need to store this somewhere, in order to retrieve it and modify it later if the program was closed.

Comment: Please give more details about your issue

Answer (score 0):

In a BASIC MODE you can do this:

1) Store in Settings (for instance) the date of application LOAD. This way, you have the current date:

```
    My.Settings.LoadDate = Datetime.Now.Tostring
    My.Settings.Save
```

2) Use BackgroundWorker and put the following code within:

```
Do
  Dim LastDate as datetime = cdate(my.settings.LoadDate)
  if datetime.now.date > LastDate
    Counter = 0
    My.Settings.LoadDate = Datetime.Now.Tostring
    My.Settings.Save
  end if
Sleep(1200)
```

3) This way, you will have a different Thread to check, on each 1.2 seconds, the current date. If Date pass by today, you will reset the Date on settings and reset also your counter.

4) This code may be optimized, but basically solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

define a timer that checks for DateTime.Now , whenever the day component changed , reset the counter

```
Dim time As DateTime = DateTime.Now
Dim count = 0L


Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'you can use settings to store and restore data
    If File.Exists("date") Then time = DateTime.FromBinary(Long.Parse(File.ReadAllText("date")))
    If File.Exists("count") Then count = Long.Parse(File.ReadAllText("count"))

    Dim t = New Timer
    t.Interval = 1000 ' one second
    t.Enabled = True
    t.Start()


    AddHandler t.Tick, Sub(ss As Object, ee As EventArgs)
                           If DateTime.Now.Day > time.Day Then
                               count = 0
                           End If
                           time = DateTime.Now
                       End Sub
    AddHandler FormClosing, Sub(ss As Object, ee As FormClosingEventArgs)
                                File.WriteAllText("date", time.Ticks.ToString())
                                File.WriteAllText("count", count.ToString())
                            End Sub
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the `DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek` value at Form level along with your Counter.  In the Load() event of the Form, set that variable.  Now check it whenever the Button is clicked and reset accordingly:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private i As Integer = 0
    Private LastDayOfWeek As DayOfWeek

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        LastDayOfWeek = DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek
        Label1.Text = i
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek = LastDayOfWeek Then
            i = i + 1
        Else
            i = 0
            LastDayOfWeek = DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek
        End If
        Label1.Text = i
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: *You changed the original question significantly after I posted, but the idea is still the same.

Comment: Thanks much, first time I am using stackoverflow.